# Have single line empty constructors, but braces on newline everywhere else

Tags: clang-format

I am looking for a way to make clang-format allow single line empty constructors, but to put braces on the newline everywhere else.

Ideally I want to support these three cases all with one clang config.

```
Test::Test(const std::string &name) : name(name) {}

std::string Test::get_name()
{
    return name;
}

void Test::blank()
{
}
```

Is there a way to special case constructors in anyway? Even being able to have empty functions on a single line the same as constructors would be acceptable. But putting short functions on a single line is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't solve all the issues, but it solves my main case.

```
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: InlineOnly
```

This will allow short functions in class definitions to be single line.

From https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

> SFS_InlineOnly (in configuration: InlineOnly) Only merge functions defined inside a class. Same as “inline”, except it does not implies “empty”: i.e. top level empty functions are not merged either.

```
class Foo {
  void f() { foo(); }
};
void f() {
  foo();
}
void f() {
}
```

This combined with BreakBeforeBraces: Allman gives me the desired result.